# Convert sqlalchemy ORM query object to sql query for Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy

This question feels fiendishly simple but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I have an ORM query object, say

```
query_obj = session.query(Class1).join(Class2).filter(Class2.attr == 'state')
```

I can read it into a dataframe like so:

```
testdf = pd.read_sql(query_obj.statement, query_obj.session.bind)
```

But what I really want to do is use a traditional SQL query instead of the ORM:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    # Execute the query against the database
    results = connection.execute(query_obj)
    # Fetch all the results of the query
    fetchall = results.fetchall()
    # Build a DataFrame with the results
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(fetchall)
```

Where query is a traditional SQL string.  Now when I run this I get an error along the lines of "query_obj is not executable"  Anyone know how to convert the ORM query to a traditional query?  Also how does one get the columns in after getting the dataframe?

Context why I'm doing this: I've set up an ORM layer on top of my database and am using it to query data into a `Pandas DataFrame`.  It works, but it's frequently maxing out my memory.  I want to cut my in-memory overhead with some string folding (pass 3 outlined here: http://www.mobify.com/blog/sqlalchemy-memory-magic/).  That requires (and correct me if I'm wrong here) not using the read_sql string and instead processing the query's return as raw tuples.

Comment: What is exactly your question? Just how to put the results of a fetchall into a dataframe? Further, what is not working about the code above? It seems fine to me.

Comment: For the column names, you can get that from `fetchall.keys()`

Comment: I made an edit to clarify my question.  I'm just not clear on how to convert the ORM query_obj into a SQL string.

Comment: See the docs here: http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined

Comment: :)  I see the answer.  If you post I'll give you answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The long version is described in detail in the FAQ of sqlalchemy: http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined

The short version is:

```
statement = query.statement
print(statement.compile(engine))
```

The result of this can be used in `read_sql`.

Comment: The link is no longer valid.

Comment: The new location seems to be here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/faq/sqlexpressions.html#how-do-i-render-sql-expressions-as-strings-possibly-with-bound-parameters-inlined.

Answer (score 2):

this may be a later version of sqlalchemy since the post.

```
print(query)
```

outputs the query you can copy and paste back into your script.

Answer (score 1):

Fiendishly simple indeed.  Per Jori's link to the docs, it just `query_obj.statement` to get the SQL query.  So my code is:

```
with engine.connect() as connection:
    # Execute the query against the database
    results = connection.execute(query_obj.statement)
    # Fetch all the results of the query
    fetchall = results.fetchall()
    # Build a DataFrame with the results
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame(fetchall)
```